# Convert value of an Ansible variable from lower case to upper case

Tags: linux, ansible

I am working on a playbook to join linux systems to Active Directory.
I can't seem to find a way to convert the value of ansible_hostname to uppercase. One of the commands I need to run requires the hostname to be supplied in uppercase.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet because I have not been able to find a documented way to do it.

Comment: Could you add an example, an expected outcome and explain why you need this (context)? Why does the hostname need to be in UPPERCASE?

Comment: Please add the code snippet you have so far so that people can add the missing code

Comment: This may belong in stackoverflow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23195321/how-to-convert-string-to-uppercase-lowercase-in-jinja2

Answer (score 95, accepted):

As [Hector Valverde](https://serverfault.com/users/284385/hector-valverde) mentionned, it seems to be

```
{{ ansible_hostname|upper }}
```

...rather than "uppercase"

Comment: Similarly, there's also `{{ ansible_hostname | lower }}` instead of [Jinja2's documented `lower()`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#lower)

Answer (score 8):

In my case to convert the value of a variable to uppercase pipe the variable to upper like so:

```
{{ ansible_hostname|upper }}
```

Comment: How did you find this? Did you read some documentation?

Comment: It should be documented on http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_filters.html but like many things in Ansible it's assumed you "just know"; I'm often frustrated by this as well. E.g. there are multiple examples of how to define a host variable (ntp server is used as an example) but how to actually *use* such a host variable is not explained anywhere.

Comment: Actually is: {{ ansible_hostname|upper }}

Comment: @wurtel See http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#builtin-filters for all the filters that aren't documented directly at Ansible.